# Nesting select with laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5

Is it possible to create nested option fields in a form drop down
and check what the exactly option user select using `$request->has()` method

it's working well with the name of `<select name="name">`

Thanks

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: nothing it's know the name for `<select>` only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change `name="name"` to `name="name[]"` so the multiple values can be parsed.